# Rails form_for select tag with option selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a form_for to update a user profile.

As part of the form I am using a select menu. The menu is filled from an array ie,

```
STATUS = [['Active', 'active'], ['In Active', 'inactive']]
```

Then in the form

```
<%= f.select(:status, options_for_select(STATUS)) %>
```

While this work's its not selecting the option which was previously selected on edit.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<%= f.select(:status, options_for_select(STATUS, :selected => params[:status])) %>
```

should be written as

```
<%= f.select :status, STATUS %>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what '==>' means... Which of the above lines is the answer? Thanks!

Comment: It's the second one. The helper does it for you as it knows the relevant value from the model.

Answer (score 3):

In the case that params doesn't do it for you, try

```
<%= f.select(:status, options_for_select(STATUS, :selected => f.object.status)) %>
```

Comment: In Rails5, the official doc shows:
`options_for_select(container, selected = nil)`
which means the second parameter should be a value not options.


So it should be:
`<%= f.select(:status, options_for_select(STATUS, f.object.status)) %>`
in Rails5