# How do I set a selected option in this Rails 2 selection form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2, form-helpers

I am editing a Rails 2 application. In it, a user submits a form that includes a dropdown menu, and that information creates a record in my database. When the user goes to edit the record, I want to show the saved "selected" option in the dropdown menu. I keep getting errors, however. Here is my set-up:

**View Select Field**

```
    <% form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :start, options_for_select(@itinerary.locations), {:include_blank => true}, {:id=>"startdrop" } %>
```

**Form Helper**

```
    def options_for_select(locations)
  locations.map do |l|
    content_tag "option", l.masterlocation.name, location_option_attributes(l)
  end.join("\n")
end

private

def location_option_attributes(location)
  {
    :value => "#{location.masterlocation.street_address}, #{location.masterlocation.city}, #{location.masterlocation.state}, #{location.masterlocation.zip}",
    :id => location.masterlocation.id,  
    :"data-masterlocation-name" => location.masterlocation.name,
    :"data-masterlocation-id" => location.masterlocation.id,
    :"data-masterlocation-latitude" => location.masterlocation.latitude,
    :"data-masterlocation-longitude" => location.masterlocation.longitude
  }
end
```

I have tried making the view look like this:

```
    <%= f.select :start, options_for_select(@itinerary.locations, @newsavedmap.start), {:include_blank => true}, {:id=>"startdrop" } %>
```

But I get wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)) for that line. Also tried

```
    <%= f.select :start, options_for_select(@itinerary.locations), {:selected => @newsavedmap.start, :include_blank => true}, {:id=>"startdrop" } %>
```

But nothing is preselected when I go to edit the saved map. I've tried following these links, and keep striking out. Appreciate any help you have to offer!

[Rails select helper - Default selected value, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623458/rails-select-helper-default-selected-value-how) , [Rails form_for select tag with option selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332030/rails-form-for-select-tag-with-option-selected) , [Rails select helper - Default selected value, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623458/rails-select-helper-default-selected-value-how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this in your helper

```
   def options_for_select(locations, selected=nil)
      locations.map do |l|
        tag_options = location_option_attributes(l)
        if l == selected
         tag_options[:selected] = "selected" 
        end
        content_tag "option", l.masterlocation.name, tag_options
      end.join("\n")
    end
```

then call field like you were trying before.

```
<%= f.select :start, options_for_select(@itinerary.locations, @newsavedmap.start), {:include_blank => true}, {:id=>"startdrop" } %>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Unfortunately, this results in an error: undefined local variable or method `location'. I think the error refers to the helper, though it points to the view code you provided.

Comment: @KDP I have updated my answer, one of the variables was named incorrect, 'location' should have been 'l'

Comment: Thanks, Barlow! If you've got the time, I'd really appreciate help with some of my other Rails questions on SO (most recent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622224/moving-options-from-one-select-field-to-another-using-form-handlers-in-rails and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603320/why-isnt-rails-recognizing-nil-if-blank-in-my-form)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass one more parameters to select the value like this:

```
<%= f.select :start, options_for_select(@itinerary.locations), :selected => @newsavedmap.start,  {:include_blank => true}, {:id=>"startdrop" } %>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but when I create a record with this code and then try to edit it, no option is selected. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure your field is updated? Can you do a SQL query to see if the value is there in the database itself?